# Problem with simple python game using a pygame libray

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new at Python and Pygame and I started making a simple game, something like a tennis game, but every time ball is under the rectangle jumping +-5 pixels and blocking. I think the problem is with pXY and bXY.

```py
import sys, pygame
from pygame.locals import *



pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((500,500)) # ustawiwanie wielkosci
pygame.display.set_caption(("little shit")) #ustawianie nazwy

okienko = pygame.display.get_surface() # pobieranie płaszczyzny


 # obiekt
prostokat = pygame.Surface((80,20)) # tworzenie prostokąta / tulpa, szerokość / wysokość
prostokat.fill((128, 15, 220))  # zmiana koloru prostokąta / r:g:b
pXY = prostokat.get_rect() # pobranie wymiarów prostokąta
pXY.x = 225 # wartość x
pXY.y = 460 # wartość y


kolko = pygame.image.load("./ball.png")
bXY = kolko.get_rect()
bXY.x = 120 # POŁOŻENIE OBIEKTU
bXY.y = 200 # POŁOŻENIE OBIEKTU

bx,by = 5,5 # o ile sie przesuwamy
px = 3

bAB = kolko.get_rect()
bA = 25
bB = 25
kolko = pygame.transform.scale(kolko,(bA,bB))


pygame.display.flip() # wyświetlenie/odrysowanie całego okna


fps = pygame.time.Clock() # ile czasu minęło od wykonywania instrukcji


while True:


    okienko.fill((128, 128, 128))  # zmiana koloru płaszczyzny na szary

    pXY.x += px

    if pXY.x > 420 or pXY.x < 0:
        px *= -1
    okienko.blit(prostokat, pXY)

    bXY.x +=bx
    if bXY.x > 475 or bXY.x < 0:
        bx*= -1
    bXY.y +=by
    if bXY.y > 475 or bXY.y < 0:
        by*= -1
    if pXY.colliderect(bXY): # KOLIDACJA OBIEKTOW
        by=5

    okienko.blit(kolko, bXY)
    pygame.display.update() # update okienka
    fps.tick(30) # odswiezanie obrazu, 30 fps


    for zdarzenie in pygame.event.get():
        if zdarzenie.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        if zdarzenie.type == KEYDOWN:
            if zdarzenie.key == K_LEFT:
                px=-7
            if zdarzenie.key == K_RIGHT:
                px=7



while True: # pętla do zamykania okienka
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
```

When the ball is under the rectangle, jumping +- 5 pixels and blocking, the ball can't leave this area when is on the left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your collision detection logic will not give physically accurate results. For example, no matter where the ball collides with the paddle it will always start moving downward at 5 pixels/frame. This means that the ball will pass through the paddle when it collides hits from above but it will 'bounce' if it hits from below. That is what causes the ball to behave the way it does. This line is where the velocity is set if the paddle and ball are colliding:

```
if pXY.colliderect(bXY): # KOLIDACJA OBIEKTOW
    by=5
```

A slightly better approach would be to reverse the direction of the ball if it collides with the paddle. But this still makes the ball only reverse direction in the y-axis no matter where on the paddle the ball collides (top, bottom, left, right). The code above can be changed to this code to get this effect:

```
if pXY.colliderect(bXY): # KOLIDACJA OBIEKTOW
    by*=-1
```

This final chunk of code is cleaned up a bit and translated to English. It uses the second block of code from above to bounce the ball off the paddle:

```
import sys

import pygame


pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption('new caption')

paddle = pygame.Surface((80, 20))
paddle.fill((128, 15, 220))
paddle_rect = paddle.get_rect()
paddle_rect.x = 225
paddle_rect.y = 460

ball = pygame.Surface((25, 25))
ball.fill((255, 0, 0))
ball_rect = ball.get_rect()
ball_rect.x = 120
ball_rect.y = 200

ball_velocity_x = 5
ball_velocity_y = 5
paddle_velocity_x = 3

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    # event processing code
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                paddle_velocity_x = -7
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                paddle_velocity_x = 7

    # update code
    # update the position of the paddle and bounce it off the edges of the window
    paddle_rect.x += paddle_velocity_x
    if paddle_rect.x > 420 or paddle_rect.x < 0:
        paddle_velocity_x *= -1

    # update the position of the ball and bounce it off th eedges of the window
    ball_rect.x += ball_velocity_x
    ball_rect.y += ball_velocity_y
    if ball_rect.x > 475 or ball_rect.x < 0:
        ball_velocity_x *= -1
    if ball_rect.y > 475 or ball_rect.y < 0:
        ball_velocity_y *= -1

    if paddle_rect.colliderect(ball_rect):
        ball_velocity_y *= -1



    # drawing code
    window.fill((128, 128, 128))
    window.blit(paddle, paddle_rect)
    window.blit(ball, ball_rect)
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(30)
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, but your code is working only if paddle_rect.y < ball_rect.y

Comment: i mean, when paddle_rect.y is for example 300, ball is jumping again and again